# Error with SSL routines:: unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

Tags: ubuntu, python, ssl, https, openssl

I have been trying to do a webscraping from [this site](https://cnae.ibge.gov.br/?view=secao&tipo=cnae&versaosubclasse=10&versaoclasse=7&secao=A).

When I use the browser to acess, the website opens normal.

But when I try to use R or Python, I have a few errors like: `Error in open.connection(x, "rb"): error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled`.
How can I solve it?

I tryed to download the certificate and put it in the same folder as the webscraping files, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70977935/why-do-i-receive-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-ssl-c997). But did not solve

My script in R:

```r
# Definindo url
url <- "https://cnae.ibge.gov.br/?view=secao&tipo=cnae&versaosubclasse=10&versaoclasse=7&secao=A"

# Configurando proxy
#httr::set_config(httr::use_proxy(url = url, port = 8080))

sessao_inicial <- httr::GET(url)
#> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle): error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled

page = rvest::read_html(url)
#> Error in open.connection(x, "rb"): error:0A000152:SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled
```

My script with Python

```python
import requests

concla = requests.get('https://cnae.ibge.gov.br/?view=secao&tipo=cnae&versaosubclasse=10&versaoclasse=7&secao=A', verify="scripts/certificado_para_webscrap.pem")

#SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cnae.ibge.gov.br', port=443): 
#Max retries exceeded with url: /?view=secao&tipo=cnae&versaosubclasse=10&versaoclasse=7&secao=A 
#(Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION_DISABLED] unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled
#(_ssl.c:997)')))
```

I have been using Pop Os 22.04.